# How to get the first correction for the cumulant expansion of a weakly inteacting gas (dilute gas)?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm reading Statistical Physics of Particles by Mehran Kardar for my Statistical Mechanics class. In the Interacting Particles section, he discusses about writing the partition function $Z$ in terms of the cumulant expansion for the interacting potential $u(\vec{q_1},...,\vec{q_N})$:

$$\ln{Z}=\ln{Z_0}+\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-\beta)^l}{l!}\langle u^l\rangle_c^0$$

specifically, he discusses the interactions in the dilute gas, specializing the interaction potential as a pairwise one:

$$u(\vec{q_1},...,\vec{q_N})=\sum_{i<j}\nu(\vec{q_i}-\vec{q_j})$$

After that, he gets the first conrrection for the cumulant expansion:

[image]

What I don't understand is how the change of variables is done. What I have tried is making $\vec{q}=\vec{q_i}-\vec{q_j}$ and then defining the center of mass coordinates of both $\vec{q_i}$ and $\vec{q_j}$ as $\vec{Q}=(\vec{q_i}+\vec{q_j})/2$, thus the differentials are

$$d^3q=d^3q_i-d^3q_j$$ $$d^3Q=\frac{1}{2}(d^3q_i+d^3q_j)$$

I tried multiplying both, but i got:

$$d^3qd^3Q=\frac{1}{2}(d^3q_i-d^3q_j)(d^3q_i+d^3q_j)=\frac{1}{2}(d^3q_id^3q_i-d^3q_jd^3q_j)\neq d^3q_id^3q_j.$$

Comment: That unfortunately (as much as it seems like it should!) is not how integration by substitution works, and not how you manipulate differentials in the context of integration by substitution. The Jacobian of that transformation is 1, and so $d^3qd^3Q=d^3q_1d^3q_2$.

Comment: @march The Jacobian would be $$J(\vec{q},\vec{Q})=\left| \frac{\partial(\vec{q_i},\vec{q_j})}{\partial(\vec{q},\vec{Q})} \right| $$?

Comment: Yes, the determinant is the correct Jacobian and if you compute it, it will be 1.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think I'm doing something wrong. As I understood, the Jacobian matrix would be $$\left[\frac{\partial\vec{q_i}}{\partial\vec{q}},\frac{\partial\vec{q_i}}{\partial\vec{Q}} ; \frac{\partial\vec{q_j}}{\partial\vec{q}}, \frac{\partial\vec{q_j}}{\partial\vec{Q}}\right]$$, but the determinant of that is 4. What am I missing?

Comment: This is in Mathematica, but you see the matrix of the Jacobean.  It is six-by-six because there are six variables. `x`, `y`, and `z` are your $\vec{q}$, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are your $\vec{Q}$. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhmXl.png